# mysql - How to perform joining of of two junctional tables in case where one of them has foreign key of another?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, junction-table

I am new in the database design, so I am still learning, so sorry for maybe inappropriate terms using, so I will try to explain on common language what problem I have. I learned how to join two tables (getting result) over junction table which is in between, but I got into problem when I want to join one "regular" table and one junction table over another junction table.

I have a relational database which has tables and relations between them like this:

[image: Relational database design]

I know how to join `hgs_transliterations`, `hgs_gardiners`, `hgs_meanings`, `hgs_word_types` using `hgs_translations`, but what I don't know how to do is how to join those 4 tables and the `hgs_references` table.

This is my code for joining lower 4 tables:

```
SELECT hgs_transliterations.transliteration, hgs_gardiners.gardiners_code, hgs_meanings.meaning, hgs_word_types.word_type
FROM hgs_translations
JOIN hgs_transliterations ON hgs_translations.transliteration_id = hgs_transliterations.id
JOIN hgs_gardiners ON hgs_translations.gardiners_id = hgs_gardiners.id
JOIN hgs_meanings ON hgs_translations.meaning_id = hgs_meanings.id
JOIN hgs_word_types ON hgs_translations.word_type_id = hgs_word_types.id
```

I read some tutorials on this subject which mention `AS`, `INNER JOIN`, `OUTER JOIN`, but I didn't quite understand terminology and how I can use this to create what I need. Sorry for maybe basic questions, but as I say, I am just a beginner and I am trying to understand something deeply so I can use it appropriately. Thank you in advance.

P.S. If someone thinks that this is not good database design (design of relations between tables), I would like to hear that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add two more joins:

```
SELECT hgs_transliterations.transliteration, hgs_gardiners.gardiners_code, 
       hgs_meanings.meaning, hgs_word_types.word_type,
       hgs_references.reference
FROM hgs_translations
JOIN hgs_transliterations ON hgs_translations.transliteration_id = hgs_transliterations.id
JOIN hgs_gardiners ON hgs_translations.gardiners_id = hgs_gardiners.id
JOIN hgs_meanings ON hgs_translations.meaning_id = hgs_meanings.id
JOIN hgs_word_types ON hgs_translations.word_type_id = hgs_word_types.id    
JOIN junc_translation_reference ON junc_translation_reference.translation_id = hgs_translations.id
JOIN hgs_references ON hgs_references.id = junc_translation_reference.reference_id
```

Comment: 1) I don't have **hgs_translation_reference** table (you probably meant **junc_translation_reference**). 2) Did you purposely left **junc_translation_reference** without **.reference_id**, or not?